# Aegir Drush Drupal 6

Tags: 6, drush

I am using the Hosting module through Aegir. I created a module with some extra fields such as "site_name," "fields," and "description," which was done successfully. I want to use these fields on a newly created website. I am using this code in the new site:

```
function silverpack_config_menu() {
  // Create additional primary menu items
  $items = array(
    array('link_path' => '<front>', 'link_title' => t('Home'), 'weight' => 0),
    array('link_path' => 'node/2', 'link_title' =>t(drush_get_option('site_name')), 'weight' => 6),
    array('link_path' => 'node/3', 'link_title' => t('Contact'), 'weight' => 8),
     array('link_path' => 'node/4', 'link_title' => t('Contact US'), 'weight' => 10),
     array('link_path' => 'node/5', 'link_title' => t('Terms & Conditions'), 'weight' => 10),
     );

  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item += array(
      'mlid' => 0,
      'module' => 'menu',
      'has_children' => 0,
      'options' => array(
        'attributes' => array(
          'title' => '',
        ),
      ),
      'customized' => 1,
      'original_item' => array(
        'link_title' => '',
        'mlid' => 0,
        'plid' => 0,
        'menu_name' => 'primary-links',
        'weight' => 1,
        'link_path' => '',
        'options' => array(),
        'module' => 'menu',
        'expanded' => 0,
        'hidden' => 0,
        'has_children' => 0,
      ),
      'description' => '',
      'expanded' => 0,
      'parent' => 'primary-links:0',
      'hidden' => 0,
      'plid' => 0,
      'menu_name' => 'primary-links',
    );
    menu_link_save($item);
  }


}
```

Here, I want to use `drush_get_option('site_name')`. "site_name" is one of the fields I use in Aegir's Hosting module.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: i followed these steps http://groups.drupal.org/node/97039. Still not working

Comment: I don't quite understand why your question is so long. The code doesn't seem relevant to what you are asking? Can you please elaborate, or shorten the question? Is your question simply how to query aegir/hosting/provision for current sites name?

Comment: No,  i want to use some extra fields like steps in groups.drupal.org/node/97039.but not working here

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have not returned the `$items` array before exiting `hook_menu`. I assume it is a typo, but just incase it is not, you need to insert `return $items;` before the end of the function.

You need to check whether or not Drupal is able to fetch the value returned by `drush_get_option()`.

Can you check in your hook_init(), the value of `drush_get_option()`?

Something like the following code should work.

```
function silverpack_config_init(){
  $test_sitename = drush_get_option('site_name');
  dsm($test_sitename);// Install Devel Module to use dsm()
}
```

Clear the cache, and refresh twice to see if you receive anything back from Drupal. If it is not returning anything, that means either "site_name" is not registered in your database table, or drush is not getting the context properly.